# How do I access the data from a referenced firestore document?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My data in firestore is structured as shown in the pictures. In my code, I am using a map of the `exercises` array within my `workout` document like this:

```
{workout.exercises.map((exercise) => {
    return (
        <Text>Want exercise name here</Text>
    )
```

I believe I have to use `doc.data()` from `getDoc(exercise).then((doc) =>`  to get the actual values, but I can't seem to figure out how to actually render the exercise name. It's driving me crazy, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

This is the `exercise` object referenced in the `exercises` array from the picture above:

[image]

**EDIT**: If the `exercises` array only has one element, it works properly, but if it has >1, the data seems to keep rendering infinitely which results in flashing and changing text.

**EDIT2**: Here's my full component code in case that helps:

```
export function WorkoutDisplayScreen({ navigation }) {
  const [workouts, setWorkouts] = React.useState([]);
  const workoutsArray = [];
  const [isFirstLoad, setIsFirstLoad] = useState(true);
  const [exerciseData, setExerciseData] = useState({});

  async function getData(exercise) {
    await getDoc(exercise).then((doc) => {
      setExerciseData(doc.data());
    });
  }

  const getWorkouts = async () => {
    console.log('Firebase READ & WRITE');
    const workoutsCollection = collection(db, 'Users', auth.currentUser.uid, 'Workouts');
    const workoutsDocs = await getDocs(workoutsCollection);
    workoutsDocs.forEach((workout) => {
      workoutsArray.push(workout.data());
    });

    setWorkouts(workoutsArray);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Rendering...');
    if (isFirstLoad) {
      getWorkouts();
    }
    setIsFirstLoad(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScreenContainer>
      <View style={styles.headerrow}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.goBack();
          }}
        >
          <AntDesign name="leftcircle" size={24} color="black" style={styles.headericon} />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.header}>My Workouts</Text>
      </View>

      {workouts &&
        workouts.map((workout) => {
          return (
            <View key={workout.id}>
              <View style={styles.workoutnamecontainer}>
                <Text style={styles.workoutnametext}>{workout.name}</Text>
              </View>
              {workout.exercises.map((exercise, index) => {
                getData(exercise);

                return (
                  <View style={styles.exercisecontainer} key={index}>
                    <Text style={styles.exercisetext}>{exerciseData.name}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.exercisetext}>{exerciseData.type}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.exercisetext}>{exerciseData.weight}</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.exercisetext}>{exerciseData.reps}</Text>
                  </View>
                );
              })}
            </View>
          );
        })}
    </ScreenContainer>
  );
}
```

**EDIT3**:
I can now log the data in the correct format with, but trying to render it on screen is still not working correctly.

```
  const getWorkouts = async () => {
    console.log('Firebase READ & WRITE');
    const workoutsCollection = collection(db, 'Users', auth.currentUser.uid, 'Workouts');
    const workoutsSnapshot = await getDocs(workoutsCollection);
    let workoutsDocs = workoutsSnapshot.docs;
    workoutsDocs.forEach((workout) => {
      workoutsArray.push(workout.data());
    });
    setWorkouts(workoutsArray);

    workouts.map((workout) => {
      workout.exercises.forEach((exercise) => {
        getDoc(exercise).then((doc) => {
          console.log(workout.name + ':');
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      });
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should do all the data-fetching i.e. for all the workouts and every exercise in each workout in the useEffect itself. I have never seen code where data fetching is done inside the JSX part of the function. I am highly skeptical about it.

Also, one thing I noticed while looking through your code is that you are iterating over the snapshot instead of docs in the the snapshot inside your ***getWorkouts()*** function. It should be as follows:

```
const getWorkouts = async () => {
  console.log('Firebase READ & WRITE');
  const workoutsCollection = collection(db, 'Users', auth.currentUser.uid, 'Workouts');
  const workoutsSnapshot = await getDocs(workoutsCollection);
  workoutsDocs = workoutsSnapshot.docs; // This line must be added to your code
  workoutsDocs.forEach((workout) => {
    workoutsArray.push(workout.data());
  });

  setWorkouts(workoutsArray);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm using your code now to get the workouts, and am using:

workouts.map((workout) => {
      workout.exercises.forEach((exercise) => {
        getDoc(exercise).then((doc) => {
          console.log(workout.name + ':');
          console.log(doc.data());
        });
      });
    });

to get the exercises associated with each workout document correctly. I'm just now sure how to take it from the `console.log` to rendering on the screen. It doesn't seem to work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah it is, I'm getting data, there's just an infinite loop with constant re-rendering of the data I'm getting back

Comment: Instead of forEach loop on workouts.exercises, you will have to do a for..in.. loop because the latter will not move on the the next iteration until the getDoc is complete, which is the behaviour we want.